# Clarification of the meaning of 'universal claims' vs 'particular individual claims' in Social Policy

Tags: united-kingdom, social-welfare

I am studying Social Policy in the UK, and I am unsure of the meaning of a question which I have been set: 'How should Social Policy respond to particular individual claims whilst addressing universal claims to wellbeing across all of society?'

Do individual claims to wellbeing relate to individual freedoms as somebody in a US libertarian tradition might understand it?
Or do they relate to Intersectionalism, where the claimant may have unique individual claims because of their unique combination of needs stemming from the unique way their various demoographic attributes overlap (eg age, ethnicity, disability status, gender etc etc etc), to make them require a unique package of welfare such as a unique package of affirmative action?
Or does this question refer to welfare benefits which are not means tested (addressing universal claims to wellbeing) vs means tested welfare benefits (addressing individual claims to wellbeing)?

NB: the lecture with the question at the end covered topics in no particular order like having multiple identities and levels of identity across the life course, the role of intersectionality, and discrimination/needs relating to age, ethnicity, disability, gender, culture, identity, equal opportunity, and the Divisions of Welfare as described by [Titmuss](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/841C6F9C4DB23FBAD61DC4A9181885BB/S0047279408002523a.pdf/remembering_and_rethinking_the_social_divisions_of_welfare_50_years_on.pdf) (1955).

I appreciate any help because I am prone to misunderstanding questions and going off on tangents without addressing the main issue. NB, I am a complete newby, should my question be unsuitable for the forum but salvageable then I would appreciate constructive criticism on how to improve it!